# OpenAI from Langchain requires "openai_api_key" even though it is loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, openai-api, langchain, large-language-model

this is my code:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv,find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

print(os.environ.get("OPEN_AI_KEY"))

from langchain.llms import OpenAI
llm=OpenAI(model_name="text-davinci-003",temperature=0.7,max_tokens=512)
print(llm)
```

when I execute above code I get this error

```
ValidationError: 1 validation error for OpenAI
__root__
  Did not find openai_api_key, please add an environment variable `OPENAI_API_KEY` which contains it, or pass  `openai_api_key` as a named parameter. (type=value_error)
```

docs say

> If you'd prefer not to set an environment variable you can pass the
> key in directly via the openai_api_key named parameter when initiating
> the OpenAI LLM class:

But already set it and it prints correctly

[image]

When I set the `llm` by passing named param:

```
llm=OpenAI(openai_api_key="PASSINGCORRECTKEY", model_name="text-davinci-003",temperature=0.7,max_tokens=512)
llm("Tell me a joke")
```

then I get this error:

```
raise ValueError(
             "Argument `prompt` is expected to be a string. Instead found "
            f"{type(prompt)}. If you want to run the LLM on multiple prompts, use "
             "`generate` instead."
         )
```

### UPDATE

env variable initially was set as `OPEN_AI_KEY` since I copied and pasted from one of my other project which calls `chat/completions` api. I changed the env to `OPENAI_API_KEY` not I get this error:

```
AuthenticationError: Incorrect API key provided: org-Wz3J****************2XK6. You can find your API key at https://platform.openai.com/account/api-keys.
```

But same api key works when i call `"https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions"` endpoint

Comment: I hope ur are not making typo on env variable name ,it should be same as `openai_api_key`

Answer (score 3):

You may need to store the OpenAI token and then pass it to the `llm` variable you have here, or just rename your environment variable to `openai_api_key`.

A possible example of passing a key directly is this:

```python
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv,find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv())

prompt = "Your Prompt Here"
OpenAI_key = os.environ.get("OPEN_AI_KEY")
print(OpenAI_token)

from langchain.llms import OpenAI
llm=openai.Completion.create(model_name="text-davinci-003",temperature=0.7,max_tokens=512,openai_api_key=OpenAI_key, prompt=prompt, stop=None)
print(llm)
```

It should work now

Comment: this gives me a different error when I run `llm("Tell me a joke")`

Comment: Can you paste the error here (censor the key), or update the question? Maybe your key is invalid?

Comment: if it was not valid, it would say quota is over or 429 error. I used expired api keys before, so i created a new api key with new phone registration

Comment: try this code, it *should* work now

Answer (score 2):

Your env variable must have the key name `OPENAI_API_KEY` This should solve your problem:

`OPEN_AI_KEY` => `OPENAI_API_KEY`

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the error in **Jupyter Notebook**

*Did not find openai_api_key, please add an environment variable `OPENAI_API_KEY` which contains it, or pass `openai_api_key` as a named parameter. (type=value_error)*

For the people who are using Jupyter Notebook:

```
%env OPENAI_API_KEY="sk-XXXXXXXXX"
```

Solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

you should add a .env file and add the open_api_key in it

```
open_api_key="xxxx"
```

Comment: I did and already loaded

Comment: add a line like
openai.api_key = 'xxxxxx'
and try

Answer (score 0):

I was getting similar error but Passing openai_api_key as one the parameters resolved the issue.

```
api_key= 'sk-xxxxxxxxxxxx'
chat = ChatOpenAI(temperature=0, model=llm_model,openai_api_key=api_key")
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to add OPENAI API KEY is to put it in a system environment.

- Go to system environment variable
- click on Environment Variables (Right Bottom corner)
- Generated New System Env Variable in User Variables for User
- Add OPENAI_API_KEY as Variable Name
- Add 'Your_Api_key' in Variable value
- Now Restart your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

For people using google colab, if `%env` didn't work for you, try instead:

```
import os
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = 'sk-XXXXXXXXX'
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are using an old OPENAI_API_KEY, regenerate a new one, and use it in your project and the problem will be solved.